# How to display an unordered list into a JSX <ul> element in a React Form using class component

Tags: reactjs, forms, class, jsx, controlled-component

I'd like to write an unordered list compiled from a form's input values into a `<ul>` when I click on the `Submit` button. It's a controlled form in a class based component. Unfortunately I haven't found out how I can achieve it without hooks.

```
export default  class  App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
        this.state = {
            name: "",
            email: "",
            message: "",
            demo: "",
          };

        this.changeHandler = this.changeHandler.bind(this);
        this.submitFormHandler = this.submitFormHandler.bind(this);
    }

  
    changeHandler = (e)  => { 
        this.setState = {
            name: e.target.value,
            email: e.target.value,
            message: e.target.value,
            demo: ` 
      <li>${this.state.name}</li>
      <li>${this.state.email}</li>
      <li>${this.state.message}</li> `
      };
    this.setState(this.setState)
  };

    submitFormHandler = (e)  => { 
    e.preventDefault();
    // I guess the solution will be here somehow
    };
    
    render() { 
    return (
        <form  onSubmit={this.submitFormHandler} > 
            
            <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>    <br/>
            <input id="name" type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.changeHandler} />
            <br/>
            <label htmlFor="mail">E-mail:</label>    <br/>
            <input id="mail" type="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.changeHandler} />
            <br/>
            <label htmlFor="msg">Message:</label>    <br/>
            <textarea id="msg" type="email" value={this.state.message} onChange={this.changeHandler} />

            <h4>Values of the inputs:</h4>
            <ul id="demo">
                {this.state.demo}  {/* the list would be here! */}
            </ul>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            
        </form>
        );  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To show something when it is submitted I would make a `isSubmitted` flag. Also you controlled inputs were not working. When inputs `ids` are corresponding with `names` in state we can easier handle them in onChange handler function. Also when it is submitted we can prevent user from updating data in `changeHandler` with early return. So I fixed it in code below:

```js
// import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      message: '',
      isSubmitted: false,
    };

    this.changeHandler = this.changeHandler.bind(this);
    this.submitFormHandler = this.submitFormHandler.bind(this);
  }

  changeHandler = ({ target }) => {
    if (this.state.isSubmitted) return;

    this.setState({ [target.id]: target.value });
  };

  submitFormHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ isSubmitted: true });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.submitFormHandler}>
          <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label> <br />
          <input
            id="name"
            type="text"
            value={this.state.name}
            onChange={this.changeHandler}
          />
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="email">E-mail:</label> <br />
          <input
            id="email"
            type="email"
            value={this.state.email}
            onChange={this.changeHandler}
          />
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="message">Message:</label> <br />
          <textarea
            id="message"
            type="email"
            value={this.state.message}
            onChange={this.changeHandler}
          />
          <br />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>           
        </form>            
        {this.state.isSubmitted && (
          <React.Fragment>
            <h4>Values of the inputs:</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>{this.state.name}</li>
              <li>{this.state.email}</li>
              <li>{this.state.message}</li>
            </ul>
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Omg, thanks but it looks awful! I guess it would be simpler if I convert it to functional component and use useStates for every input and another one for the ```<ul>``` instead. I just hoped it's not necessary but seeing this it is.

Comment: What seems awful for you? It is just one handler for all inputs, no matter how many of inputs you have.